# remove comments from php file using sed

Tags: php, linux, bash, sed

i'm trying to edit a php config file using sed in a bash script. I'm stuck on removing comments from particular lines. I want to uncomment line:

```
// $CFG->phpunit_prefix = 'phpu_';
```

I tried command that worked for me to replace/update paths:

```
"s%// $CFG->phpunit_prefix%$CFG->phpunit_prefix%" config.php
```

But it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: If you want to strip out comments (why do you need to) then I'd suggest using [NikiC's PHP parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) rather than sed

Comment: @Mark you mean you don't wanna use the horrendous `token_get_all()` and friends directly? :)

Comment: I'm stripping comments using a bash script, that is being executed by Continuous Integration server

Comment: Sounds like a job for an environment-specific config file, ideally.

Comment: @TomFenech - Not if I can help it; but NikiC's parser is actually very good, and handles recreating the modified file again

Comment: @TomFenech I'm trying to install moodle in a docker container and run phpunit tests. I needed to copy and edit a config.php file, which i'm doing using .yml file

Comment: I have no experience of that setup but I'm sure that there are ways of doing what you want without using sed. For example, you could define a variable in a separate config file, then conditionally run this line depending on the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is simply that you're using double quotes, so `$CFG` is being expanded by the shell. Change to single quotes:

```
sed 's%// $CFG->phpunit_prefix%$CFG->phpunit_prefix%' config.php
```

In general, I'd recommend always using single quotes except in the rare case that you're using a shell variable as part of a sed command (which comes with its own set of pitfalls).

For increased readability and to avoid repeating yourself, use a capturing group:

```
sed 's%// \($CFG->phpunit_prefix\)%\1%' config.php
```

To debug this kind of issue, use `set -x`, which will show you that the command you're executing is different to the one you intended to use.